# Specflow/Gherkin: How to handle bad data

Tags: specflow, gherkin

I am new to Specflow so here goes;

For my example below Should I test for the bad at all?  If I do the table won't let you add a bad value. So the code will error because its coming in as as bad type.   I guess I just need to know how others handle verifying the user can't enter bad data? (fields names are changed due to confidential info)
the requirement says:

Verify that the user cannot set the rate to be negative or greater than 1.  The rate range is from 0.9999 to 0.

Verify that the user cannot enter a  rate with more than 4 decimal places.

```
Given the lc does not exist  
    | Lc      |
    | Test90  |  
    | Test00  | 

    When I add a Lc  
    | Lc      | Somekind of ID|  Rate     |
    | Test90  | 2             |  0.9999   |
    | Test00  | 4             |  0        |

    Then the lc should be defined
    | Lc      | 
    | Test90  |
    | Test00  |
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue with the tables not accepting a 'bad value'. Are you getting some exception? Could you possibly provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit strange that you are testing 2 values thoughout your test.

I would be tempted to rewrite like this:

```
Scenario Outline: valid lc's can be created
    Given the lc named <lc> does not exist  
    When I add a Lc named <lc> with Id <id> and rate <rate>
    Then the lc named <lc> should be defined
Examples:
        | Lc      | Id |  Rate     |
        | Test90  | 2  |  0.9999   |
        | Test00  | 4  |  0        |


Scenario Outline: Invalid lc's cannot be created
    Given the lc named <Lc> does not exist  
    When I add a Lc named <Lc> with Id <Id> and rate <Rate>
    Then the lc named <Lc> should not be defined
    And an error should have been raised saying the rate was invalid
Examples:
        | Lc      | ID |  Rate     |
        | Test90  | 2  |  1.999    |
        | Test90  | 2  |  0.99999  |
        | Test90  | 2  |  -0.9     |
        | Test00Y | 4  |  6        |
        | Test00Y | 4  |           |
```

The `And an error should have been raised saying the rate was invalid` step is obviously optional but shows that this is expected to fail due to an invalid rate.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  When you say it's strange that I am testing 2 values, how should it be done?  don't I need to test for all scenarios that are valid?  like in this case they can enter a value of 0 or a value from 0.0001 thru 0.9999.  but they cannot leave it blank or have negs or whole numbers.

Comment: Whats strange is not that you are testing 2 values, just that you are testing 2 values via tables rather than examples. I have given examples of using a Scenario Outline with examples instead of using multiple tables. This allows you to easily add more tests for different values (like the negative numbers and empty values (which I just added))

Comment: I also corrected to use Scenario Outlines which are necessary with the examples.

Comment: Is it better to just put 1 test value and have a test for each?  Are the examples comments in the gherkin?  sorry this is all new to me.

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines). Each example is a single test which runs the scenario with the values plugged in.

Comment: Gherkin is the language that cucumber and specflow understand.

Comment: Above is how I would implement this in Specflow.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I will do some playing.